# Thunderbird 60.6.1 not printing: only option is print to file (ubuntu 18.04 minimal install)

Tags: printing, thunderbird

Thunderbird 60.6.1 (Ubuntu 18.04 minimal install) doesn't show any printers, only shows the print to pdf option.  The printer is working correctly for all other applications.

Thunderbird works correctly for Ubuntu 19.04 full install.

I've tried looking in the TB config file (preferences --> advanced) but didn't see anything that looked out of place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the same disagreement.

I found the following solution (but not the best one)

1. When printing to file, TB creates a file called `mozilla.pdf`
2. Rename immediately that file `<chosenName>.pdf`
3. Move the new file to some appropriate folder
4. Open the file & print it.

I'd have better preferred not to copy my mailbox under distiller...

Waiting for  the ABSOLUTE answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the Ubuntu Software Center to install Thunderbird, it is probably a Snap install with restricited permissions. I had the same problem and the solution is the following:

1. Go to Ubuntu Software Center, at the Thunderbird page
2. There are three buttons: 'Launch', 'Remove' and 'Permisisons'
3. Go to the last one and enable the 'Printers' permission

Restart Thunderbird and there you go.